# Client cannot Connect to Remote Rabbitmq Server

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, google-compute-engine

I'm running a Rabbitmq server on Machine A where tasks can be put into the message queue. Machine B is supposed to connect to the AMQP server on Machine A and do the tasks. My `rabbitmq-env.conf` settings are:

```
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=
NODE_PORT=5672
```

I can connect to the server on Machine A locally. When run `nmap -p 5672 localhost`. It shows:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000094s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5672/tcp open  amqp
```

But on Machine B, when running Celery worker, it says:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://myuser:**@{server_IP}:5672/myvhost: timed out.
```

`nmap -p 5672 {server_IP}` shows:

```
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5672/tcp filtered amqp
```

I can be sure that my Broker url setting in Celery is correct and I'm not using a guest account for rabbitmq.

My server status shows:

```
[{pid,2580},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.2.4"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.14"},
                        {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.5"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.11"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.4"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.4"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,40419400},
          {connection_procs,205272},
          {queue_procs,60240},
          {plugins,0},
          {other_proc,13473800},
          {mnesia,75128},
          {mgmt_db,0},
          {msg_index,30440},
          {other_ets,748888},
          {binary,5264592},
          {code,16522377},
          {atom,594537},
          {other_system,3444126}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,1552420044},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,6313250816},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,924},
                    {total_used,7},
                    {sockets_limit,829},
                    {sockets_used,3}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,153}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,8}]
...done.
```

Both Machine A and Machine B are Google Compute Engine VMs under the same project. Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What OS are you running on these VMs? The VM may have a firewall that prevents external connections other than SSH by default (CentOS default installation is like this, I believe).

Comment: Can you connect to the 5672 port using telnet from the client machine?

Comment: @MishaBrukman I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the VM. I think it is Google's security policy that bans any outside connection to VM. It worked when I changed the IP to an internal IP, which is allowed by default.

Comment: @TomKregenbild It worked for me now. It turned out to be the firewall issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a security issue. Rabbitmq by default listens to all Internet interfaces and allows remote connections as long as the account used is not guest. For connections between GCE instances, internal IP addresses or simply instance names should be used. Internal connections are allowed by default. But external ones are forbidden by google. So just change the 'server_IP' to the internal IP or instance name, and all works like magic.